# What is between oscillator and antenna for a simple carrier transmitter

Tags: rf

I have a 20.000 Mhz Crystal Oscillator Module. If I just wanted to transmit a carrier wave at 20 megahertz, what would be from A to B?[image]

Comment: It depends on how strong a signal you want to transmit; you may need an amplifier of some sort. Also, you'll almost certainly want a filter of some sort to limit the bandwidth of the transmitted signal. For example, if it's a square-wave oscillator, you'll want to eliminate the harmonics at 60, 100, 140, etc. MHz. This could be accomplished with a simple L-C tank circuit.

Comment: I checked with my scope, and the wave looked sine

Comment: @skyler are you sure your new scope has the bandwidth to show a decent squarewave at 20MHz without it looking a bit rounded and sinusoidal. A simple output filter would help clean things up and because it's unlikely you'll be using a full 3m 1/4 wave antenna (because you might get into trouble with the authorities) there are passive filters that might get you +6dB output on the bare oscillator o/p

Comment: It's rather difficult to answer this question without more specific information. Maybe you need nothing. Maybe you want an impedance matching network. Maybe you want an amplifier. What are the components? What are the requirements?

Comment: @andy aka : My scope is the owon pds5022. I am very new to it so maybe my settings are off

Comment: @skyler Do note that your oscilloscope has only 25 MHz analog bandwidth and a sample rate of only 100 Msamples per second. That's a pretty bad scope for RF use. Short version of the story is: Scope will see only one half of the amplitude of the 25 MHz signals (also called -3 dB point) and can't see correctly any signals above 50 MHz. In my opinion, even a square 20 MHz wave will look pretty sinusoidal on such scope. For the long story, search this site for oscilloscope questions, we have a lot of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be an ATU (aerial tuning unit) consisting of inductances and variable capacitors.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Keep the output clean with a filter that can apply a little gain at 20MHz. Here's an unusual one that gives higher Q the more you load it: -

[image]

This has been simulated from an earlier filter design I did but you'll still need to tweak values such as C1 and C3 - I suggest 10pF trimmers.